# How to call top link after the searchbar

Tags: magento2

How to move top link after the search bar(like sign in and create account).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet after **`<body>` tag** into your theme's **default.xml** file.

File Path - **app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.search" />
```

If you have moved search bar on top menu and you want to move toplinks after search bar then you can use the following code snippet in **default.xml** file.

```
<move element="top.links" destination="header.panel" after="top.search" />
```

Hope this will help you.